# Java: using the "||" and "&&"

Tags: java, if-statement

I was hoping some one might be able to assist me with this issue. What I am try to accomplish, A user will enter a word or a small phrase. Then it will request 4 numbers (`int`). From there the program will use the 4(ints) entered and extract a `char` from that position.  `"I love java"  7 8 9 10`  output: `"java"`. If a user enters a number greater then the phrase I want it to display a message.  I am using the `String.length()` to compare the 4 `int` numbers provided to ensure they are not greater then the phrase. when i use one variable it works fine, but when i add `&&` it toss the following message... any suggestions?.... From what i can see it looks fine

```
Line: 37
bad operand types for binary operator '&&'
first type:  boolean
second type: int


import java.util.Scanner;

 class FunString{

 public static void main(String[] arg){

 String userinput;

 int fristnum;

 int secondnum;

 int thirdnum;

 int fourthnum;

 char finalfristnum;

 char finalsecondnum;

 char finalthirdnum;

char finalfourthnum;
int userinputlegnth;  

  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Please enter a word:");
userinput = scan.next();
fristnum = scan.nextInt();
secondnum = scan.nextInt();
thirdnum = scan.nextInt();
fourthnum = scan.nextInt();

 userinputlegnth  = userinput.length();

  if(userinputlegnth < fristnum && secondnum && thirdnum  ){


 finalfristnum = userinput.charAt(fristnum);
 finalsecondnum = userinput.charAt(secondnum );
 finalthirdnum = userinput.charAt(thirdnum );
 finalfourthnum = userinput.charAt(fourthnum );

 System.out.println(finalfristnum + " " + finalsecondnum + " " + finalthirdnum     + " " + finalfourthnum);
}else{

System.out.println("WRONG");
}


}

}
```

Comment: That is not valid Java syntax. It should be: `if(userinputlegnth < fristnum && userinputlegnth < secondnum && userinputlegnth < thirdnum  ){`

Comment: Note that while one `&` will compile, it won't do what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct logic would be:

```
if(fristnum < userinputlegnth &&
   secondnum < userinputlegnth &&
   thirdnum < userinputlegnth &&
   fourthnum < userinputlegnth){

    finalfristnum = userinput.charAt(fristnum);
    finalsecondnum = userinput.charAt(secondnum );
    finalthirdnum = userinput.charAt(thirdnum );
    finalfourthnum = userinput.charAt(fourthnum );
} else ...
```

Explanation: A number selecting a character from a string must be less than the length of that string:

```
*num < userinputlegnth
```

If you have two such numbers, both must meet this condition, which requires logical and (`&&`) to combine two conditions:

```
fristnum < userinputlegnth   &&   secondnum < userinputlegnth
```

And a condition such as `a < b` is met, if the *smaller* value is on the left hand side.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(userinputlegnth < fristnum && secondnum && thirdnum  )
```

This shortcut you are trying is not valid syntax.

Use :

```
if ((userinputlegnth < fristnum) && 
    (userinputlegnth < secondnum) && 
    (userinputlegnth < thirdnum))
```